# Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles

Tags: java, soap, authorization, websphere, jax-ws

I have web application with SOAP interface developed on JAX-WS. And I get error **Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles: AUTHENTICATED**  Could you give me some pieces of advice?
My config is:
**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>AuthConstr</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AuthConstraint</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>All HAI authenticated users</description>
        <role-name>AUTHENTICATED</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>AUTHENTICATED</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

**application.xml** is:

```
<security-role id="SecurityRole_AUTHENTICATED">
    <role-name>AUTHENTICATED</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**ibm-application-bnd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_1.xsd"
             version="1.1">

<security-role name="AUTHENTICATED">
    <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/>
</security-role>
```

Also in Java WS I use annotation

```
@RolesAllowed("AUTHENTICATED")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when you are getting this error but at least, I think that you need to exclude the login page from secured URL pattern. Nobody can be already authenticated at the same time at is asked for authentication.
I mean that if you place all your secured "resources" under path "secured" you could set `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` as `<url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>` and avoid to secure login page.